# PDO connection file wont connect to phpMyAdmin, live site. Keep getting message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I have a connection file done up with PDO. When I try to connect to my live database, I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused.

I did everything I could think of to try to get this to work. But I keep getting:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused.

I am trying to connect to a live database with phpMyAdmin. Here's my code...

```
<?php
$servername = "10.xxx.x.85:3306";
$username = "nephilim42_341";
$password = "rxxxxxxxxxx3";

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=wdv341", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database';
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Mysql will need to be set with the bind address if you want to access it remotely. Firewall need to allow it. And you are connecting to mysql not phpmyadmin or myphpadmin

Comment: @frz3993 Ill do more research on the bind address. I am using mysql to access my database from myphpadmin from my web-hosting service.

Comment: Add connecting to mysql with tls into your research too